# How to use multiple DTOs in a selection using Spring JPA Criteria Build

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I am currently developing an application where I may need to filter the result on N differents ways. Doing some research I've found that using predicate is a good method to create dynamics queries. The problem that I am facing happens when I try to create a query from a DTO which has another DTO on it.
For example, imagine that you have an entity named "UserManager" which has an entity named "User" and another one named "Car".
Then you create a DTO called "UserManagerDTO" which has, on it, a DTO named "CarDTO", as illustrated below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userManager")
public class UserManager implements Serializable {
    private User user;
    private Car car;
    private long id;
    private Date timestamp;
    ...
} 


public class UserManagerDTO {
...
    public UserManagerDTO(long id, long userId, String email, String userName, 
CarDTO carDTO, Date timestamp ){
...
}

public class CarDTO {
...
    public CarDTO(String name, String type){
    ...
}
```

With the presented case in mind, how may one do a select using UserManagerDTO, which has CarDTO on it, using CriteriaQuery?

The way that I tried to do, which gave me the following error: "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ," is presented below:

```
    String userId = queryParameters.get(USER_ID);
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserManagerDTO> cq = cb.createQuery(UserManagerDTO.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    Root<UserManager> entity = cq.from(UserManager.class);
    Predicate p1 = cb.and(cb.equal(entity.get("user").get("id"), Long.parseLong(userId)));
    cq.where(p1);
    Expression<String> exp1 = cb.concat(entity.get("user").get("name"), " ");
    exp1 = cb.concat(exp1, entity.get("user").get("lastName"));
    Selection<CarDTO> select1 = cb.construct(CarDTO.class,
            entity.get("car").get("name"), entity.get("car").get("type"));
    Selection<UserManagerDTO> select2 = cb.construct(UserManagerDTO.class, entity.get("id"),
            entity.get("user").get("id"), entity.get("user").get("email"), exp1, select1, entity.get("timestamp"));
    cq.select(select2);
    TypedQuery<UserManagerDTO> query = em.createQuery(cq);
```

The error was presented on the comma right before "select1" on the "select2" variable.

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I need to combine multiple DTOs in construct as well